# isomorphisms- subspaces in topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following topological spaces: $(X_1,\tau_1)=(\Bbb R,\tau_u)$ and $(X_1,\tau_2)=(\Bbb R, \tau_{kol})$

So the product topology is the following: $(\Bbb R^2, \tau_u \times \tau_{kol})$

I have to describe the subspace topology defined by each subsets.

$A=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: x+y=0\}$
$B=\{(0,0)\} \cup \{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: xy=1\}$

In other words, I have to say to which topological space is isomorphic $(A, \tau_A)$ and $(B,\tau_B)$, respectively.

Could you help me please? I have defined the base of each topology but I can't see any isomorphism.

*Note: $\tau_{kol} = \{ (a,\infty): a \in \Bbb R \} \cup \{\emptyset,\Bbb R\}$ (Topology of Kolmorogov)

and $\tau_u$ is the usual topology

Thank you for your time

Comment: What is $\tau_{kol}$ ?

Comment: What is $\tau_u$?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: See Blanca's edit.

Comment: By "$R$", do you mean $\mathbb{R}$, the real numbers?

Comment: Write `\Bbb R` to get $\Bbb R$ and `\infty` to get $\infty$ or just paste this `∞`. You can type `\{` to make a $\{$ and `\cup` or `∪` to make a $\cup$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product has a base of open sets of the form $U(a,b,c)=(a,b)\times(c,\to)$, where $a,b,c\in\Bbb R$ and $a<b$;

$$U(a,b,c)=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:a<x<b\text{ and }c<y\}\;.$$

You need to investigate how these basic open sets intersect $A$ and $B$.

- $A$ is just the graph of the line $y=-x$. Show that each $U(a,b,c)$ intersects $A$ in an open interval of the line $A$, and that each open interval on $A$ can be obtained in this way. This means that $A$ in its subspace topology is homeomorphic to what familiar space?
- $B$ is the graph of a rectangular hyperbola together with its centre point. Here again you should look at the intersections $B\cap U(a,b,c)$ of $B$ with basic open sets in the product. You’ll find that a lot of them are open intervals of $B$. However, you’ll find that $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is **not** an isolated point of $B$ in this topology, though it is in the usual topology; every $U(a,b,c)$ that contains $\langle 0,0\rangle$ also contains other points of $B$.